# How to run javascript using ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ng-bind-html` which is running html code fine but when I tried to run JavaScript code using script tag it did not work. see example over [here (Fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/km31gwvx/).

```
app.js file 
app.constant('text',"<script>alert('this is alert')</script>");
  app.constant('color', 'blue' );



controller.js 
 var module = angular.module('cntrl');

  module.controller('DCtrl', function(
      $scope,
      $timeout,text,color) {

    $scope.bannertext=text;
    $scope.bannercolor=color;
  });

frontend.html
<div ng-bind-html="bannerText"> </div>
this is giving me normal text like <script>alert('this is alert')</script> so how i can run javascript uisng above code
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here, could you clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is intentional. Allowing scripts to run like that are a major security risk.

Comment: I think your problem is that you need to replace the `<` with `&lt;`. Also your Fiddle should specify that it is using angular as a library in the "Frameworks and Extensions" section

Comment: @vogomatix sanitize should remove all that, and for good reason. I think that OP should consider using a controller or services for whatever functionality they are trying to accomplish instead of inline scripts - however it is unclear the end result.

Comment: @ajmajmajma: he makes it clear he's only put the scripts inline for demo purposes.

Comment: As per requirement in app.constant('text'," "); value of text would be html, css or javascript code. html and css running fine but only JavaScript code is not running in that

Comment: Why would you save your code in a constant like that?

Comment: @ajmajmajma its kind of configuration so one who wants to display some admin message or notification or alert , then he can directly add all things in value of text variable

Comment: Why not use a provider for that?

Answer (score 0):

Imcomplete answer, but see changed JSFiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/km31gwvx/1/

1. Replace `<` with `&lt;` entity
2. Specify Angular as library in Frameworks and Extensions